# Pivot table while maintaining the index of the row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["ip", "state", "ip", "state", "jobs", "ip", "state", "status"],
                   'col2': ["10-0-11-99", "running","10-0-11-19", "running", "0/344","10-0-11-23", "running", "on"]})

    col1      col2
0   ip  10-0-11-99
1   state   running
2   ip  10-0-11-19
3   state   running
4   jobs    0/344
5   ip  10-0-11-23
6   state   running
7   status  on
```

I want to convert it to the following format

```
          ip    state   jobs    status
0   10-0-11-99  running Nan     Nan
1   10-0-11-19  running 0/344   Nan
2   10-0-11-23  running Nan     on
```

I used following code to convert it but `cumcount` gives the wrong index. I am running out of ideas/ways to solve the problem :

```
cols = df.groupby(['col1'],sort=False).aggregate(np.sum).reset_index()['col1'].to_list()
df['index'] = df.groupby(df['col1'])['col1'].cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='col1', values='col2')
df = df.reindex(cols, axis=1)

col1    ip     state    jobs      status
index               
0   10-0-11-99  running 0/344      on
1   10-0-11-19  running NaN       NaN
2   10-0-11-23  running NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest and straight forward way to do it is to loop over your `df` with simple logic, so we don't need worry about index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["ip", "state", "ip", "state", "jobs", "ip", "state", "status"],
                   'col2': ["10-0-11-99", "running","10-0-11-19", "running", "0/344","10-0-11-23", "running", "on"]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ip", "state", "jobs", "status"])

new_row = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col1'] in new_row:
        new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        new_row = {}

    if row['col1'] not in new_row:
        new_row[row['col1']] = row['col2']
new_df = new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)
```

Outputs:

```
           ip    state   jobs status
0  10-0-11-99  running    NaN    NaN
1  10-0-11-19  running  0/344    NaN
2  10-0-11-23  running    NaN     on
```

Answer (score 0):

A key assumption is that `ip` determines how the data will be transposed, and will always be present. We can then check for rows that have `ip`, do a cumulative sum, build a multiindex, and unstack :

```
res = df.assign(temp=df.col1.eq("ip").cumsum())
res

    col1    col2      temp
0   ip      10-0-11-99  1
1   state   running     1
2   ip      10-0-11-19  2
3   state   running     2
4   jobs    0/344       2
5   ip      10-0-11-23  3
6   state   running     3
7   status  on          3
```

Build the MultiIndex:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([res.col1.unique(), 
                                    res.temp.unique()], 
                                    names=["col1", "temp"])

MultiIndex([(    'ip', 1),
            (    'ip', 2),
            (    'ip', 3),
            ( 'state', 1),
            ( 'state', 2),
            ( 'state', 3),
            (  'jobs', 1),
            (  'jobs', 2),
            (  'jobs', 3),
            ('status', 1),
            ('status', 2),
            ('status', 3)],
           names=['col1', 'temp'])
```

Final phase is to set the index and reindex with `index`:

```
res.set_index(["col1", "temp"]).reindex(index).unstack("col1")

                               col2
col1    ip      jobs    state   status
temp                
1   10-0-11-99  NaN     running NaN
2   10-0-11-19  0/344   running NaN
3   10-0-11-23  NaN     running on
```

You can reset the index, but that's trivial, so I did not bother with it.

On a side note, you can abstract the index building process to expose the missing rows by using the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
import janitor

res.complete(["col1", "temp"]).pivot("temp", "col1", "col2")
```